# I am not able to perform dynamically added java script

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, editor

I have created an html, css, javascript code editor using reactjs. where the javascript written is not working as html and css are working fine.
Here is the App component

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';


function App() {
  const [html, setHtml] = useState("");
  const [css, setCss] = useState("");
  const [js, setJS] = useState("");
  const htmlTemplate = useRef();
  const cssTemplate=useRef();
  const jsTemplate=useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    htmlTemplate.current.innerHTML = html;
  }, [html])
  useEffect(()=>{
    cssTemplate.current.innerHTML = css;
  },[css])
  useEffect(()=>{
    jsTemplate.current.innerHTML = js;
  },[js])

  return (
    <>
      <div className="editor">
        <div contentEditable className="code" onInput={e => setHtml(e.target.textContent)}>
        </div>
        <div contentEditable className="code" onInput={e => setCss(e.target.textContent)}>
        </div>
        <div contentEditable className="code" onInput={e => setJS(e.target.textContent)}>
        </div>
      </div>
      <script className="xyz" ref={jsTemplate}></script>
      <div className='container' ref={htmlTemplate}></div>
      <style ref={cssTemplate}></style>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The Html code is

```
<button class="button" value="OK" type="button">Click Here</button>
```

Java script to handle the button

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName('button')[0]
x.addEventListener('click',hello);
console.log(x)
function hello(){  
alert("hello javatpoint user");  
}
```

Can any one help me out with this issue.

Comment: In your script, do you actually run the code? It' possible that you only inject the function but that doesn't mean that it would auto run. You also need to call the script maybe?

Comment: Yes but how should I should I run it.